# Is it better to use sql hint /*+ opt_param('_optimizer_use_feedback' 'false') */ in the select statement

Tags: sql, indexing, oracle11g

The execution plan:

Plan 1:

```
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Id  | Operation                   | Name                     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |                          |       |       |     9 (100)|          |
  |   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| EMP_HISTORY              |     1 |   190 |     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |
  |   2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN          | IND_EMP_HISTORY_VALDT    |    15 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Plan 2:

```
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Id  | Operation                   | Name                   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |                        |       |       |   281 (100)|          |
  |   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| EMP_HISTORY            |     3 |   570 |   281   (0)| 00:00:04 |
  |   2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN          | IND_EMP_HISTORY_EMPNO  |  1203 |       |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I did for first plan1 by disabling the setting parameter "_OPTIMIZER_USE_FEEDBACK"  = FALSE  at database level, but this is not suitable because it may effect other query.For second paln the sql hint /*+ opt_param('_optimizer_use_feedback' 'false') */  used in select statement.

Could anyone please advice.

Thanks,
Raju

Comment: Hi Marc_s, it is oracle 11g

Comment: Hi, I ran the query: select * from emp_history where empno='1234' and hire_dt='12 February 2014' and region='USA' and reference_no like '%789456%' and salary='2300.50'. If I ran first time will return the rows in 5 secs but again I ran the same query it is taking 20 mins to fetch rows. Please advice. Thanks

Comment: That isn't one of the settings [the hint supports](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements006.htm#BABEBAID), according to the 11gR2 docs. You may be able to enable it with `alter session`, instead of setting it at database level. Maybe you should explain what problem you're trying to solve and why you think this is the solution. There may be better ways to fix original your problem. Checks your stats are up to date, to start with.

Comment: Hi Alex, The above query ran without the sql hint. For first time it took 5 sec and second time took 35 mins to return the rows. Please advice. Many thanks

Comment: Hi Alex, Could you please advice. Many thanks.

Comment: Hi Alex, I have used index sql hint, it worked well. Many thanks

Comment: Hi All, If I used index sql hint, It may have any effects?. Please suggest.